LWC template for:each not working
I am having trouble that Foreach tag not working in HTML . I want get a list from apex in JS, and loop the list in HTML. but I have got the list in js , but it don't display in HTML.
The js code ：
import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import QueryCreditLimitCheck from '@salesforce/apex/AccountCreditLimitChange.QueryCreditLimitCheck'
export default class Lwc_Account_Credit_Limit extends LightningElement {
    dataList = [];
    dataArray = [];
    @track displayDataList  ;
    @track dataError ;
   
  
    @wire(QueryCreditLimitCheck)  AccountCreditDAOList(error,data){
 
        if(error.data){
             this.datalist = error.data;
            
             this.dataLength = this.datalist.length;
             console.log( 'AccountCreditDAOList.data '+  this.datalist);
             console.log( 'AccountCreditDAOList.data '+  this.datalist[0].OpportunityName);
             console.log( 'AccountCreditDAOList.data '+  this.datalist);
             
             
        }else{
            this.dataError = error;
        }
       
    };
   
}

The list display in webConsole log . 
the html foreach code as :
<template>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label="Credit &amp; Collections">
            <div class="c-container">
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                    <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" size="12">
                        <div class="page-section page-header">
                            <h2>Account Credit Limit Management</h2>
                        </div>
                        <template for:each={dataList} for:item="acc">
                            <div key={acc.Id}>
                                <p  >{acc.AccountId}</p>
                                <p  >{acc.OpportunityId}</p>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" size="12">
                        <div class="page-section page-right">
                            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered"
                                aria-label="Example default base table of Opportunities">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Opportunity Name</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Amount">Amount</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Close Date">Close Date</div>
                                        </th>

                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Request Contract">Contact</div>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <template for:each={dataList} for:item="acc">
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={acc.Id}>
                                            <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="OpportunityName">
                                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1">{acc.OpportunityName}</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <td data-label="Account Name">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">{acc.AccountName}</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td data-label="Close Date">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">{acc.CloseDate}</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td data-label="Amount">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="$25k">4</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td data-label="Remind">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="jrogers@cloudhub.com">
                                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1">5</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </template>


                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </lightning-layout-item>

                </lightning-layout>
            </div>

        </lightning-tab>
        <!-- 第二个Tab-->
        <lightning-tab label="Finance" title="Finance">
            第二个Tab
        </lightning-tab>

    </lightning-tabset>
</template>


if(error.data) { this.datalist = error.data;
doesn't make sense, it should be
if(data) { this.datalist = data;

sorry，it is my fault .  I can get the right data . and  this.datalist can be put the array list . whitout display to html
